# Need to change date format in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript

Currently using Date() gives it in format

```
Wed Jul 05 2017 15:14:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

i want to change it so that I get it in this format (want GMT time not IST)

```
Jul 5 15:14:53 2017 GMT
```

I also want to know how I can get the time say 2 years from now.

EDIT:

I have fixed the format but now having problems in setting it up to gmt time instead of ist fixed it by :

```
let d = new Date();
let month = d.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "short" });
let datestring = month + " " + d.getDate() + " " + (d.getHours()) + ":" + (d.getMinutes())+ ":" +d.getSeconds() + " " + (d.getFullYear()+2) + " GMT";
```

but naturally that does not actauly show the gmt, its just IST so now trying to fix that.

Comment: if it's stored in a string variable just use "slice" to show it the way you want, example :  `{{data_time | slice:0:10}}` ...etc, try it and you'll figure out the rest, hope it helps.

Comment: Try using the `date` pipe, assuming you are trying to output the date. Are you?

Comment: i have fixed the format and all but now the problem is coming in changing the current time to gmt time...

Comment: But 15:14 in India is not 15:14 GMT. Why would you want to display a time in India as if it were a time in GMT, when it is not?

Comment: @torazaburo i have added an edit

Comment: If you want to display in GMT, then please edit your question to show the desired output as `Jul 5 09:44:53 GMT`.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use a library as momentjs.com.

```
moment(mydate).add(1, 'year');
```

Moment provide method to compare 2 dates...etc. I think i will fit your needs.

Comment: I would also create an agular2 pipe.

Comment: Perfect, use moment.js. I do.

Comment: ya that might work but is there no way to do it without having to download that library? Also dont wanna separate the date components and concatenate cause that's not really a clean way to write.

Comment: Have a look at angular 2 date pipes. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate date in angular like that. does this help!

```
  const date = new Date();
           const year = date.getFullYear();
           const month = date.getMonth();
           const day = date.getDay();
           console.log(year);
           console.log(year + 2);
           date.setFullYear(year + 2, month, day);
           console.log(date);
           console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library and get the date in GMT time as follows:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'gmtDate'
}) export class GmtDate implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Date, addYear: number = 0): string {
        // utc() - turns date into GMT
        return moment(value).add(addYear, 'year').utc().format("MMM D HH:mm:ss YYYY")
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
          <h2>{{myDate | gmtDate}}</h2>
          <h2>{{myDate | gmtDate:2}}</h2>
        </div>
    `,
}) export class App {
    myDate: string = new Date();;
}
```

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview) demo of above pipe.